# Triming a paragraph

Tags: php, trim

Hi I'm trying to trim a paragraph. What I would like is to have 2 lines of text and when you click on the trimed content it expands and the rest of the content is shown.

This is my code

```
$str.=' <div class="page-heading">
        <span class="titlechange">'.$this->title.'</span>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div>';        
$str.='         
<div class="content-box-wrapper newsfeed">
<div class="content-box-container">';

    foreach($this->boxes as $box){

        if($htag > 6){
        $htag=6;
        }
        $str.='<div class="news-heading expand-next-content">';
        $str.='<div class="testimonial_content">';
        if( $box->image ) $str.= '<img class="floatleft" src="'.$_HTTP_ADDRESS."content_images/".$box->image.'" />';
            if( $box->title ){
            $str.= '<h'.$htag.'>'.$box->title.'</h'.$htag.'>';
            }

            if( $box->content ){
                if (stristr($box->content,'<p>')){
                    $str.= $box->content;
                }else{
                    $str.= '<p>'.$box->content.'</p>';
                }
            }
            $str.= '<div class="clearboth"></div>';
        $str.='</div>';


        $htag++;
        $str.='</div>';
    }

    $str.='</div>';
$str.='</div>';
$str.='     <div class="clearboth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,if you want a inline readmore functionality then use jQuery to togggle the div where the more text is displayed

Comment: cool I will do that, but what about trimming the paragraph?

Comment: keep your div hight fixed and onclick change its height to auto

Comment: in php, you can use sustring function to display a specific length of string at first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Instead, do this on the client-side, which is pretty easy.

For example:

```
<div class="block">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    max-height: 3em;
    width: 20em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;

}

.block.open {
    max-height: 100em;
}
```

JS

```
$('.block').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('open')
})
```

This should even give you a fancy animated effect ...

Comment: Hi I tried that and it didn't work the way I would like it. I found a jsfiddle that does what I would like but the only problem is that it uses jquery 1.7.2 and if I use anything higher then that then the + disappears. Here is the jsfiddle that I found [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rashomon/8vLQ9/)